# How Do I deserialize an array from Firebase Cloud Firestore if I already have a Json deserialization from the API call (flutter/dart)

Tags: json, serialization, flutter, dart, deserialization

I have this API call wherein I ask Nutritionix(API provider) for food data given a search of food name. I've already finished my JSON deserialization, however I had to serialize some parts of the response(not all) so I can put it in my database, but when I try to deserialize the Firebase data so my user can use it in my application. (Use Case is when a user force-quits the application, all locally stored variables will get cleared, thus upon launch of application I check if there is already a record in the db that the user has already logged food for breakfast/lunch/dinner today, thus just showing the saved food log in the db)

Here is what the response looks like:

```
{
    "foods": [
        {
            "food_name": "cheeseburger",
            "brand_name": null,
            "serving_qty": 1,
            "serving_unit": "item",
            "serving_weight_grams": 199,
            "nf_calories": 535.31,
            "nf_total_fat": 28.66,
            "nf_saturated_fat": 14,
            "nf_cholesterol": 95.52,
            "nf_sodium": 1176.09,
            "nf_total_carbohydrate": 39.24,
            "nf_dietary_fiber": 2.39,
            "nf_sugars": 7.16,
            "nf_protein": 30.27,
            "nf_potassium": 443.77,
            "nf_p": 364.17,
            "full_nutrients": [
                {
                    "attr_id": 203,
                    "value": 30.2679
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 204,
                    "value": 28.656
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 205,
                    "value": 39.2428
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 207,
                    "value": 4.5969
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 208,
                    "value": 535.31
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 209,
                    "value": 25.87
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 210,
                    "value": 0.2985
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 211,
                    "value": 1.8507
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 212,
                    "value": 2.5671
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 213,
                    "value": 0.9353
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 214,
                    "value": 1.5124
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 221,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 255,
                    "value": 96.2364
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 262,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 263,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 268,
                    "value": 2242.73
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 269,
                    "value": 7.164
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 291,
                    "value": 2.388
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 301,
                    "value": 356.21
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 303,
                    "value": 2.0298
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 304,
                    "value": 51.74
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 305,
                    "value": 364.17
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 306,
                    "value": 443.77
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 307,
                    "value": 1176.09
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 309,
                    "value": 5.6317
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 312,
                    "value": 0.1493
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 315,
                    "value": 0.3244
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 317,
                    "value": 49.153
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 318,
                    "value": 471.63
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 319,
                    "value": 93.53
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 320,
                    "value": 101.49
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 321,
                    "value": 93.53
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 322,
                    "value": 1.99
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 323,
                    "value": 0.398
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 324,
                    "value": 5.97
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 328,
                    "value": 0.199
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 334,
                    "value": 3.98
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 337,
                    "value": 1611.9
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 338,
                    "value": 33.83
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 341,
                    "value": 5.4924
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 342,
                    "value": 0.6368
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 343,
                    "value": 0.1194
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 345,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 346,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 347,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 401,
                    "value": 0.597
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 404,
                    "value": 0.2368
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 405,
                    "value": 0.5174
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 406,
                    "value": 8.0595
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 410,
                    "value": 1.1741
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 415,
                    "value": 0.1851
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 417,
                    "value": 31.84
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 418,
                    "value": 3.4825
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 421,
                    "value": 75.023
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 429,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 430,
                    "value": 8.756
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 431,
                    "value": 23.88
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 432,
                    "value": 7.96
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 435,
                    "value": 47.76
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 601,
                    "value": 95.52
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 606,
                    "value": 13.9957
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 607,
                    "value": 0.3861
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 608,
                    "value": 0.1313
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 609,
                    "value": 0.0975
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 610,
                    "value": 0.2149
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 611,
                    "value": 0.2527
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 612,
                    "value": 1.4428
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 613,
                    "value": 7.2177
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 614,
                    "value": 3.7651
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 615,
                    "value": 0.0398
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 617,
                    "value": 10.6306
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 618,
                    "value": 2.0079
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 619,
                    "value": 0.2527
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 620,
                    "value": 0.0577
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 621,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 624,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 625,
                    "value": 0.2149
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 626,
                    "value": 0.9174
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 627,
                    "value": 0.1552
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 628,
                    "value": 0.0975
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 629,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 630,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 631,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 645,
                    "value": 11.8584
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 646,
                    "value": 2.5154
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 652,
                    "value": 0.1751
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 653,
                    "value": 0.2726
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 654,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 672,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 687,
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 689,
                    "value": 0.0398
                },
                {
                    "attr_id": 697,
                    "value": 0
                }
            ],
            "nix_brand_name": null,
            "nix_brand_id": null,
            "nix_item_name": null,
            "nix_item_id": null,
            "upc": null,
            "consumed_at": "2019-11-12T10:40:37+00:00",
            "metadata": {
                "is_raw_food": false
            },
            "source": 1,
            "ndb_no": 21398,
            "tags": {
                "item": "cheeseburger",
                "measure": null,
                "quantity": "1.0",
                "food_group": 8,
                "tag_id": 445
            },
            "alt_measures": [
                {
                    "serving_weight": 199,
                    "measure": "item",
                    "seq": 1,
                    "qty": 1
                },
                {
                    "serving_weight": 100,
                    "measure": "g",
                    "seq": null,
                    "qty": 100
                },
                {
                    "serving_weight": 28.3495,
                    "measure": "wt. oz",
                    "seq": null,
                    "qty": 1
                }
            ],
            "lat": null,
            "lng": null,
            "meal_type": 1,
            "photo": {
                "thumb": "https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/445_thumb.jpg",
                "highres": "https://d2xdmhkmkbyw75.cloudfront.net/445_highres.jpg",
                "is_user_uploaded": false
            },
            "sub_recipe": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my Deserialization model and Serialization model so I can put it in my cloud_firestore db:

```
class Nutritionix {
  List<Food> food;
  Nutritionix({this.food});

  factory Nutritionix.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list = parsedJson['foods'] as List;
    List<Food> foodList = list.map((i) => Food.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Nutritionix(food: foodList);
  }
}

class Food {
  String foodName;
  double servingQuantity;
  double serving_weight;
  double calories;
  double totalFat;
  double saturatedFat;
  double cholesterol;
  double sodium;
  double totalCarbohydrate;
  double dietaryFiber;
  double sugar;
  double protein;
  double potassium;
  double phospate;
  List<Nutrients> nutrients;
  Photo photo;

  Food(
      {this.foodName,
      this.servingQuantity,
      this.serving_weight,
      this.calories,
      this.totalFat,
      this.saturatedFat,
      this.cholesterol,
      this.sodium,
      this.totalCarbohydrate,
      this.dietaryFiber,
      this.sugar,
      this.protein,
      this.potassium,
      this.phospate,
      this.nutrients,
      this.photo});

  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    var list = parsedJson['full_nutrients'] as List;
    List<Nutrients> nutrientsList =
        list.map((i) => Nutrients.fromJson(i)).toList();

    //TODO: FIX ALL IF NULL AND ADD OTHER SERVING SIZES
    return Food(
        foodName: parsedJson['food_name'],
        servingQuantity: parsedJson['serving_qty'].toDouble(),
        serving_weight: parsedJson['serving_weight_grams'] != null
            ? parsedJson['serving_weight_grams'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        calories: parsedJson['nf_calories'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_calories'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        totalFat: parsedJson['nf_total_fat'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_total_fat'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        saturatedFat: parsedJson['nf_saturated_fat'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_saturated_fat'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        cholesterol: parsedJson['nf_cholesterol'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_cholesterol'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        sodium: parsedJson['nf_sodium'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_sodium'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        totalCarbohydrate: parsedJson['nf_total_carbohydrate'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_total_carbohydrate'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        dietaryFiber: parsedJson['nf_dietary_fiber'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_dietary_fiber'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        sugar: parsedJson['nf_sugars'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_sugars'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        protein: parsedJson['nf_protein'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_protein'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        potassium: parsedJson['nf_protein'] != null
            ? parsedJson['nf_potassium'].toDouble()
            : 0,
        phospate:
            parsedJson['nf_p'] != null ? parsedJson['nf_p'].toDouble() : 0,
        nutrients: nutrientsList,
        photo: Photo.fromJson(parsedJson['photo']));
  }

  //JSON SERIALIZATION SO I CAN INPUT IT IN MY DB
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "foodName": foodName,
      "servingQuantity": servingQuantity,
      "serving_weight": serving_weight,
      "calories": calories,
      "totalFat": totalFat,
      "saturatedFat": saturatedFat,
      "cholesterol": cholesterol,
      "sodium": sodium,
      "totalCarbohydrate": totalCarbohydrate,
      "dietaryFiber": dietaryFiber,
      "sugar": sugar,
      "protein": protein,
      "potassium": potassium,
      "phospate": phospate,
      "photo": photo.toJson()
    };
  }
}

class Nutrients {
  int attributeID;
  double value;
  Nutrients({this.attributeID, this.value});

  factory Nutrients.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Nutrients(
        attributeID: parsedJson['attr_id'],
        value: parsedJson['value'].toDouble());
  }
}

class Photo {
  String thumbnail;
  String highRes;

  Photo({this.highRes, this.thumbnail});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Photo(
        highRes: parsedJson['thumbnail'], thumbnail: parsedJson['thumb']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return{
      "highRes": highRes,
      "thumbnail": thumbnail
    };
  }
}
```

While here is my code for getting the document(s):

```
  void checkMealsList() async {
    final mUserData = Provider.of<UserData>(context);
    final userLoggedin = mUserData.mUData;
    int index = userLoggedin.length - 1;
    List<MealsListData> mealEntry = MealsListData.mealEntry;
    print('im inside the checkmealslistfunc');
    var breakfastDocument = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(mUser.uid)
        .collection('food')
        .document(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(today))
        .collection('Breakfast');

    breakfastDocument.getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot query) {
      query.documents.forEach((f) {
        print(f.data);
          //EDITING THE INDEX OF A LIST GIVEN A CONDITION
        var newEntry = mealEntry.firstWhere((id) => id.id == f.data['id'], orElse: null);
        if (newEntry!= null){
          newEntry.meals = f.data['meals'];
          print(newEntry.meals);
          newEntry.mealType = f.data['mealType'];
          print(newEntry.mealType);
          newEntry.nutritionix = Nutritionix.fromJson(f.data['nutritionixData']);
         // print('this is ${newEntry.nutritionix.food[0].protein}');
        }
      });
    });//.catchError((onError) => onError);
  }
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
E/flutter ( 8204): #3      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
E/flutter ( 8204): #4      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter ( 8204): #5      _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
E/flutter ( 8204): #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
E/flutter ( 8204): #7      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
E/flutter ( 8204): #8      Future._completeWithValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
E/flutter ( 8204): #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
E/flutter ( 8204): #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
E/flutter ( 8204): #11     Query.getDocuments (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart)
E/flutter ( 8204): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8204): #12     _FitnessAppHomeScreenState.checkMealsList
```

Is there a problem with my Serialization method? Or should I make a separate deserialization for my Firebase records? Any help would be appreciated! :)